# nodejs 5500 port API get connect refused

Tags: node.js, linux

Using [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) to build some nodejs backend API, here is part of my code snippet:

```js
fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
        return { data: 'ok...' }
})
```

Deploy it on my [Tencent Clound Server](https://intl.cloud.tencent.com/)

Install some related dependencies, and using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to keep my application online. Using curl to test my API currectly:

```sh
curl http://localhost:5500/

{"data":"ok..."}
```

But when I tried to request my test api using public ip address: http://1.xx.xx.xx:5500/, but it reminded me: connect refused.

And I tried to use curl to test my API by 127.0.0.1, get the same error:

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:5500/
//  connect refused
```

P.S:

I have disabled firewall:
[image]

And the 5050 port is open on my cloud server:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set listen at address 0.0.0.0

```
fastify.listen(5500, '0.0.0.0', function (err, address) {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`)
})
```

[Link](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Getting-Started/) at Note

> The above examples, and subsequent examples in this document, default
> to listening only on the localhost 127.0.0.1 interface. To listen on
> all available IPv4 interfaces the example should be modified to listen
> on 0.0.0.0 like so:

```
fastify.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, address) {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`)
})
```